# What is meant by elements in same orbit have same size stabalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am looking over a proof for the Cauchy Frobenius formula, and I am having trouble exactly understanding how one step is done.

Let G be a finite group acting on non empty set S, $$I(g)=|\{s \in S  : g \star s = s \}|$$

Then the number of distinct orbits is $$N=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} I(g)$$

So the parts I do follow;

First define $f(g,s)=1$ if $g \star s= s$ and $f(g,s)=0$ else

Then fixing $s$ gives,  $$\sum_{g \in G}f(g,s)=|stab(s)|$$

fixing $g$ gives ,

$$\sum_{s \in S}f(g,s)=|I(g)|$$

So,
$$\sum_{g \in G} I(g)=\sum_{g \in G} \sum_{s \in S}f(g,s)$$$$=\sum_{s \in S} \frac{|G|}{|orb(s)|}$$

Now here is where it starts to get a bit fuzzy for me, we pick representives for each distinct orbit, $s_{1},s_{2},...s_{N}$

and then we have continuation from above

$$=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s \in orb(s_{i})}\frac{|G|}{|Orb(s_{i})|}$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{|G|}{|orb(s_{i})|}|orb(s_{i})|$$

And it notes ( As all elements in the same orbit have same size of stabilizer)

This is the part where I am confused, how to we go from the double summation directly above, to the single summation below. What is going on? Can anyone help to explain this to me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

$\sum_{s \in S} \frac{|G|}{|\textrm{Orb}(s)|} = \sum_{s \in S} \textrm{Stab}(s) = \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{s \in \textrm{Orb}(s_i)} \textrm{Stab}(s_i) = \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{s \in \textrm{Orb}(s_i)} \frac{|G|}{\textrm{Orb}(s_i)}$

The author has justified his/her steps by the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem. Since all elements in the same orbit have the same stabilizer the second equality (in this answer) holds, i.e. we can separate all the stabilizers into $N$ distinct ones and then count the number of elements in each.

Answer (score 0):

Going from the summation $\sum_{s\in S}\frac{|G|}{|orb(s)|}$ to $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s \in orb(s_{i})}\frac{|G|}{|Orb(s_{i})|}$ should be thought of as still summing over all the elements in $S$. You have merely partitioned $S$ into its distinct orbits which you have called $[s_i]$. Note that each of these $N$ orbits contains a, possibly, different number of elements from $S$. So with $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s \in orb(s_{i})}\frac{|G|}{|Orb(s_{i})|}$ the left summation is over each orbit and the inner summation is over all $s$ contained within the $i^{th}$ orbit. How many of them are there? There are $|\text{orb}(s_i)|$ of them. This is the transition from $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s \in orb(s_{i})}\frac{|G|}{|Orb(s_{i})|}$ to your last equality.